# Distinction between Directed System and Directed Set

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, measure-theory

With reference to Folland's Real Analysis on the following definition;

An increasing cofinal function $\varphi:B \rightarrow A$ from a directed system $B$ into a directed system $A$ is a mapping such that $\beta_{1} \leqslant \beta_{2}$ implies $\varphi(\beta_{1}) \leqslant \varphi(\beta_{2})$, and for every $\alpha \in A$ there is $\beta \in B$ such that $\alpha \leqslant \varphi(\beta)$.

I would like to know if the directed system imply here have the same meaning as directed set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A directed system is a set $S$ with a relation $\le$ that satisfies $\forall s \in S: s \le s$ and $\forall s,t,u \in S: (s \le t \land t \le u) \rightarrow s \le u$, so a reflexive and transitive relation (it need not a full partial order), which also has the property that for every $s_1,s_2\in S$ we have $s_3\in S$ such that $s_1\le s_3$ and $s_2\le s_3$. I think most texts would define directed set in the same way, e.g. [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_set) does.

I'd certainly say that directed set = directed system, yes.

Comment: That's incomplete. Even in the Wikipedia article cited, there's a *crucial* additional property: Given any $s, t \in S$, there is some $u \in S$ such that $s \leq u$ and $t \leq u$.

Comment: @murray added it, thx.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it seems that it has the same meaning. I have also heard that directed system is a functor from directed set to some category and its colimit (which may not exist) is called direct limit.